# Blowing one's own horn

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, phrase-request

Is there a Latin idiom for praising oneself in classical Latin?
In English one can blow one's own horn (there are variants of this saying), but I doubt *tuba sua ludere* is likely mean the right thing.
I am looking for a colorful way to put this, not just "to praise or promote oneself", but colorless suggestions are also welcome if more vivid idioms are nowhere to be found.

Ideally, I would like something that could be considered an idiom — attested several times in a similar meaning.
But if there is only a single occurrence of a juicy parable in Cicero, no need to resist sharing it…

Comment: In English, it's usually *toot your own horn* these days, as "blowing your own horn/trumpet" has unintended (or sometimes intended) comical connotations.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Good to know. I added a note in the question. Asking about idioms through a foreign language has its risks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Smith gives four options. The standard option is *gloriari*. This has a long and gloried history (groan) throughout Classical Latin, and Cicero seems especially fond of it. As usual, check [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=glorior&la=la#lexicon) for details on usage.

However, *gloriari* isn't really an idiom for 'boast', but a fairly direct correspondence. One potential idiom is *se iactare*. This is a true idiom, because it could also mean to "actively devote oneself". It also gave the present participle a meaning of "boastful." Pliny the Younger writes (*Ep*. 3.9):

> miserat etiam epistulas Romam ad amiculam quandam, **iactantes et gloriosas**, his quidem verbis: 'Io io, liber ad te venio; iam sestertium quadragiens redegi parte vendita Baeticorum.
>
> He had also sent letters to Rome to a certain friend, **boastful and vainglorious**, with these words...

For a casual idiom, this is what I would go with.

> Iste Ionias qui se semper iactat propter viginti milia punctorum...

Some other options are to use *ostentare* + acc. (whence 'ostentatious'), which I would translate as "to show off"; or *praedicare*, but that's a very rare sense, if at all (Smith has it, L&S doesn't really).

Comment: I'm not sure who you are referring to. *Ionas*, perhaps? :-) (And, to toot my own horn, it's almost 22 by now!)

Answer (score 6):

*Se iactare* seems a fairly literal translation of "show off." If you want a more colorful image, Ovid offers us a wonderful little phrase addressed to Galatea by Polyphemus:

> Saevior indomitis eadem Galatea iuvencis,
>   durior annosa quercu, fallacior undis,
>   lentior et salicis virgis et vitibus albis,
>   his inmobilior scopulis, violentior amne,
>   **laudato pavone superbior,** acrior igni,
>   asperior tribulis, feta truculentior ursa,
>   surdior aequoribus, calcato inmitior hydro.... (Ov. *M* 13:798-804)

**Laudato pavone superbior** even has a great English translation:

> Prouder than a praised peacock

It's not quite the same as "tooting one's own horn," but it definitely is a great way of conveying the image of pride!

Comment: That's a wonderful English translation! For once, the translated idiom competes with the original.

Comment: Nice one. I might start using that myself.